# Looking for a RewriteBase equivalent using RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm facing an Apache configuration issue which can be summarized like follows.

1. On a unique hosting system I have a lot of different test sites, each one in its own subdirectory, so they are accessible through an url like `myhostname.fr/sitename`.
   Hence in the corresponding `.htaccess`, the common practice is to have a `RewriteBase /sitename` before any of the `RewriteCond`+`RewriteRule` sets, and it works fine.
2. Now for one of these sites (say in the `specialsite` subdirectory) I had to create a dedicated domain so the url looks like `domainname.myhostname.fr`.
   Then for this site to work the `.htaccess` now needs `RewriteBase /` instead of `RewriteBase /specialsite`, and it works fine too.
3. Here is the trick: being not so familiar with Apache I decided to experiment and wanted to *also* keep allowed to access this site through the common url `myhostname.fr/specialsite`.

So I had to find a way to conditionally use one of the above `RewriteBase`, depending on which is the current url.

The first way I tried was to work like this:

```
<If "%(HTTP_HOST) =~ domainname\.myhostname\.fr">
  RewriteBase /
</If>
<If "%(HTTP_HOST) =~ myhostname\.fr/specialsite">
  RewriteBase /specialsite
</If>
```

But I got a HTTP 500 error, and I take much time to understand that the `<If>` directive is available as of Apache 2.4, while my hosting only offers Apache 1.3!

So (thanks to some other SO answers) I thinked to another way, which is to first do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainname\.myhostname\.fr
RewriteRule ^ - [E=VirtualRewriteBase:/]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myhostname\.fr/specialsite
RewriteRule ^ - [E=VirtualRewriteBase:/specialsite/]
```

Then prepend all further `RewriteRule` replacement with the given `VirtualRewriteBase`, like in this one:

```
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:VirtualRewriteBase}index.php [L]
```

But while it works fine for the domain-access version, it gives me an HTTP 404 error for the subdirectory-access version.
So in order to watch at how the replacement applied I changed the above rule for:

```
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:VirtualRewriteBase}index.php [R,L]
```

And I observed that the redirected url looked like this:

```
http://myhostname.fr/kunden/homepages/7/d265580839/htdocs/specialsite/index.php
```

where `kunden/homepages/7/d265580839/htdocs/` is the full document-root of my hosting.
You can notice that the document-root has been inserted *between the two parts of the original url*.
Moreover, the result is exactly the same whatever I put in place of `/specialsite/` in my `VirtualRewriteBase`!

So here is my main question: **why and how does this happen?**
Also I'm obviously interested to a possible alternative solution to achieve the double-access availibility.
But above all I would like to understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But while it works fine for the domain-access version, it gives me an
>   HTTP 404 error for the subdirectory-access version.

That's because your second condition is never matched. Indeed, `HTTP_HOST` only contains the... http host ! The `/specialsite` is part of the `REQUEST_URI` (or can also be matched in `RewriteRule` directly).

This code should work (anyway, i don't know if it would solve totally your problem, but that's a first step)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.myhostname\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=VirtualRewriteBase:/]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhostname\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/specialsite(?:/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=VirtualRewriteBase:/specialsite/]
```

Comment: As you point out, "_Indeed_, HTTP_HOST only contains the... http host !". But this is just the issue: it wasn't _indeed_ for me. I din't have a clear idea of where is the border between HTTP_HOST and REQUEST_URI in this peculiar case. So now it becomes clear... and hence simple! I tried it and it works fine. Thanks a lot for your help.